# Test class whether does it implements serializable

Tags: java, junit

I have a class that implements serializable and I need it to be there.

```
public class Alpha implements Beta {
}
```

Is there a way to check that it is implementing Beta via a unit test?

Comment: why have you attached kotlin tag? What you've posted is Java thou

Comment: sorry mistake. I remove it right away

Comment: How are you testing the serialization of your class to begin with?  (That's probably what you'd want to leverage to test this.)

Comment: Which is it? `Serializable` or `Beta`? (Not that it makes any difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to test a class is just to require that type as a parameter:

```
public void someMethod( Beta b ) {
  // ...
}
```

For Serializable, just use that type.

```
public void otherMethod( Serializable ser ) {
```

If you need a class that implements *two types,* then you should make an interface that expresses that type.

```
public interface MyType extends Beta, Serializable {}
```

Then just use `MyType` wherever you need both types.